# Saving a video file in the background of a UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, background-task

There is a simple video editor, saving video to a file is implemented in the background, implementation of the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-files-in-the-Background . The program works, but there is a nuance - saving the video in the background occurs only when the main stream is inactive, that is, when the application is minimized to the taskbar or closed. If the application is deployed then the background video save task is suspended. Tell me how to implement the background task when the main application is active? Thank you!

**Class background tasks:**

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
using Windows.Media.Transcoding;
using System.Threading;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Media.Editing;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Lumia.Imaging;
using Lumia.Imaging.Adjustments;
using Lumia.Imaging.Artistic;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using VideoEffectComponent;

namespace MediaProcessingBackgroundTask
{
    public sealed class MediaProcessingTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        IBackgroundTaskInstance backgroundTaskInstance;
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral;
        CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        MediaTranscoder transcoder;
        MediaComposition composition;

        MediaClip clip;
        EffectList effList = new EffectList();

        PropertySet configurationPropertySet = new PropertySet();
        PropertySet DustPropertySet = new PropertySet();
        PropertySet ScretcchPropertySet = new PropertySet();
        Windows.Media.Effects.VideoEffectDefinition videoEffect;

        BrightnessEffect brightnessEff = new BrightnessEffect();
        ContrastEffect contrastEff = new ContrastEffect();
        HueSaturationEffect saturationEff = new HueSaturationEffect();

        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("In background task Run method");

            backgroundTaskInstance = taskInstance;
            taskInstance.Canceled += new BackgroundTaskCanceledEventHandler(OnCanceled);
            taskInstance.Progress = 0;

            deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            Debug.WriteLine("Background " + taskInstance.Task.Name + " is called @ " + (DateTime.Now).ToString());

            try
            {
                await TranscodeFileAsync();
                ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["TranscodingStatus"] = "Completed Successfully";
                SendToastNotification("File transcoding complete.");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception type: {0}", e.ToString());
                ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["TranscodingStatus"] = "Error ocurred: " + e.ToString();
            }


            deferral.Complete();
        }

        private async Task TranscodeFileAsync()
        {
            transcoder = new MediaTranscoder();

            try
            {
                var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

                settings.Values["TranscodingStatus"] = "Started";

                var inputFileName = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["InputFileName"] as string;
                var outputFileName = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["OutputFileName"] as string;
                var redCurve = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["CurvRed"] as Point[];
                var greenCurve = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["CurvGreen"] as Point[];
                var blueCurve = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["CurvBlue"] as Point[];
                var sat = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["SatVal"];
                var brid = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["BridVal"];
                var con = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["ContrVal"];
                var dust = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["dustCVal"];
                var scetch = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["scetchCVal"];

                saturationEff.Saturation = (double)sat;
                brightnessEff.Level = (double)brid;
                contrastEff.Level = (double)con;

                CurvesEffect curves = new CurvesEffect();
                Curve RedC = new Curve();
                Curve GreenC = new Curve();
                Curve BlueC = new Curve();
                RedC.Points = redCurve;
                GreenC.Points = greenCurve;
                BlueC.Points = blueCurve;
                curves.Blue = BlueC;
                curves.Green = GreenC;
                curves.Red = RedC;

                if (inputFileName == null || outputFileName == null)
                {
                    return;
                }


                var inputFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(inputFileName);
                var outputFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(outputFileName);

                composition = await MediaComposition.LoadAsync(inputFile);

                clip = composition.Clips[0];

                effList.Add(saturationEff);
                effList.Add(brightnessEff);
                effList.Add(contrastEff);

                effList.Add(curves);

                configurationPropertySet.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Effect", effList));

                DustPropertySet = new PropertySet();
                DustPropertySet["DustCount"] = dust;

                ScretcchPropertySet = new PropertySet();
                ScretcchPropertySet["ScetchAmount"] = scetch;

                videoEffect = new Windows.Media.Effects.VideoEffectDefinition("Lumia.Imaging.VideoEffect", configurationPropertySet);

                clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(new Windows.Media.Effects.VideoEffectDefinition(typeof(Vignet).FullName, VignetPropertySet));
                clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(new Windows.Media.Effects.VideoEffectDefinition(typeof(ExampleVideoEffect).FullName, ScretcchPropertySet));
                clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(new Windows.Media.Effects.VideoEffectDefinition(typeof(Dust).FullName, DustPropertySet));
                clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(videoEffect);

                MediaEncodingProfile mp = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD1080p);



                Debug.WriteLine("PrepareFileTranscodeAsync");
                settings.Values["TranscodingStatus"] = "Preparing to transcode ";
                var startTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Starting transcoding @" + startTime);

                    var progressT = new Progress<double>(TranscodeProgress);
                    settings.Values["TranscodingStatus"] = "Transcoding ";
                    settings.Values["ProcessingFileName"] = inputFileName;

                var saveOperation = composition.RenderToFileAsync(outputFile, MediaTrimmingPreference.Precise, mp);// AsTask(cancelTokenSource.Token, progressT);

                saveOperation.Completed = (info, status) =>
                {
                    SendToastNotification("Video saved.");
                    clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Clear();
                    composition = null;
                    deferral.Complete();

                    if (status != AsyncStatus.Completed)
                    {
                        //  ShowErrorMessage("Error saving composition");
                    }

                };
               await saveOperation.AsTask(cancelTokenSource.Token, progressT);

                Debug.WriteLine("Source content could not be transcoded.");

                    var endTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
                    Debug.WriteLine("End time = " + endTime);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception type: {0}", e.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
        void TranscodeProgress(double percent)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Transcoding progress:  " + percent.ToString().Split('.')[0] + "%");
            backgroundTaskInstance.Progress = (uint)percent;
        }

        private void SendToastNotification(string toastMessage)
        {
            ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText01;
            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
            XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(toastMessage));
            ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
        }

        private void OnCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("Background " + sender.Task.Name + " Cancel Requested..." + reason.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

**Register and launch the background task**

```
MediaProcessingTrigger mediaProcessingTrigger;
string backgroundTaskBuilderName = "TranscodingBackgroundTask";
BackgroundTaskRegistration taskRegistration;

private void RegisterBackgroundTask()
        {
            // New a MediaProcessingTrigger
            mediaProcessingTrigger = new MediaProcessingTrigger();

            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

            builder.Name = backgroundTaskBuilderName;
            builder.TaskEntryPoint = "MediaProcessingBackgroundTask.MediaProcessingTask";
            builder.SetTrigger(mediaProcessingTrigger);

            // unregister old ones
            foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                if (cur.Value.Name == backgroundTaskBuilderName)
                {
                    cur.Value.Unregister(true);
                }
            }

            taskRegistration = builder.Register();
            taskRegistration.Progress += new BackgroundTaskProgressEventHandler(OnProgress);
            taskRegistration.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(OnCompleted);

            return;
        }
        private void OnProgress(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task, BackgroundTaskProgressEventArgs args)
        {
            string progress = "Progress: " + args.Progress + "%";
            Debug.WriteLine(progress);


            var ignored = Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                TextSave.Text = progress;
                ProgressSave.Value = args.Progress;
            });

        }
        private void OnCompleted(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(" background task complete");
            var ignored = Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                TasckCompleted();
            });

        }

private async void LaunchBackgroundTask()
{
    var success = true;

    if (mediaProcessingTrigger != null)
    {
        MediaProcessingTriggerResult activationResult;
        activationResult = await mediaProcessingTrigger.RequestAsync();

        switch (activationResult)
        {
            case MediaProcessingTriggerResult.Allowed:
                // Task starting successfully
                break;

            case MediaProcessingTriggerResult.CurrentlyRunning:
            // Already Triggered

            case MediaProcessingTriggerResult.DisabledByPolicy:
            // Disabled by system policy

            case MediaProcessingTriggerResult.UnknownError:
                // All other failures
                success = false;
                break;
        }

        if (!success)
        {
            // Unregister the media processing trigger background task
            taskRegistration.Unregister(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us your code, before we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the post

Answer (score 0):

> saving the video in the background occurs only when the main stream is inactive , that is, when the application is minimized to the taskbar or closed.

In your above code snippet, the background task is triggered by `LaunchBackgroundTask()` method. When the background task occurred depends on where you invoke this method that you didn't show the relative code snippet. According to your description that background task only triggered when main stream is inactive, I think you invoke this method inside the event handle which is fired once app inactive, for example, you invoked the method inside [`EnteredBackground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication#Windows_ApplicationModel_Core_CoreApplication_EnteredBackground) event. In that case, you may need to add `LaunchBackgroundTask()` method invoking foreground to meet your requirements, for example, just invoke it in a button click event.

```
private void btnlaunch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LaunchBackgroundTask();
}
```

The `MediaProcessingTask` is [out-of-process background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task), once the background task is triggered, no matter the app is active or inactive it will continue running. But if you mean re-deployed, by testing on my side, this will uninstall the app firstly which will un-register the background task and force it stopped.